# Control gmediarenderer or BubbleUPnP from command line

Tags: linux, command-line

I use [gmediarenderer](http://gmrender.nongnu.org/) on a Linux machine, as a home media server. [BubbleUPnP](https://www.bubblesoftapps.com/bubbleupnpserver/) handles playlist synchronisation across devices so that tracks can be played over a wireless network (e.g. from a smartphone). Is there some way I can execute basic commands (such as play/pause, next track, previous track etc) from the Linux command line?